# How can you iterate through an Rx observable list of ViewModels and inflate the views

Tags: observable, rx-java2, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I need to go through the list of viewmodels, inflate the views and add them to the linearLayout. Any tips on how to do this are greatly appreciated.

```
  @BindingAdapter({"items", "provider"})
    public static void populateLinearLayout(LinearLayout layout, @Nullable Observable<List<ViewModel>> items, @Nullable int provider) {
        if (items == null) {
            return;
        }

        ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding;
        layout.removeAllViews();

        for (ViewModel vm :
                items) {
                viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(layout.getContext()), provider, layout, false);
                viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, vm);
                viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
                layout.addView(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
        }
        layout.invalidate();
    }
```

This does not work as I cannot use the forEach on the Observable, but the code in the loops is what I need to execute on the items of the list.

Comment: You need to observe the `Observable` and as soon as list of items is emit, execute your code. Observable is not iterable.

Comment: so something like? `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .forEach(item -> {`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working using the following:

```
@BindingAdapter({"items", "provider"})
public static void populateLinearLayout(LinearLayout layout, @Nullable Observable<List<ViewModel>> items, int provider) {
    if (items == null) {
        return;
    }

    layout.removeAllViews();

    items.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .forEach(item -> {
                for (ViewModel viewModel:
                     item) {
                    ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(layout.getContext()), provider, layout, false);
                    viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, viewModel);
                    viewDataBinding.executePendingBindings();
                    layout.addView(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
                }
            });
    layout.invalidate();
}
```